# How to use @htmldropdownlist with Jquery UI widgets

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, asp.net-mvc, jquery-ui

I have a dropdown list

```
 @Html.DropDownList("selectSize", Model.Sizes, "--select--",  new { id = "dd1", @class = "ddl"  })
```

And i want to use Jquery UI widgets to give it a top search section, so like a dropdown but if you type it filters the dropdown,

i currently have this code

```
<script type="text/javascript">



    $(".dd1").combobox();

    $("dd1").combobox();
    $("[name='selectSize']").autocomplete();
    $("[name='selectSize']").combobox();


    </script>
```

here im trying to change the drop down, the code for the widget i have in a script also which is:

```
<script>
(function ($) {
    $.widget("custom.combobox", {
        _create: function () {
            this.wrapper = $("<span>")
              .addClass("custom-combobox")
              .insertAfter(this.element);

            this.element.hide();
            this._createAutocomplete();
            this._createShowAllButton();
        },

        _createAutocomplete: function () {
            var selected = this.element.children(":selected"),
              value = selected.val() ? selected.text() : "";

            this.input = $("<input>")
              .appendTo(this.wrapper)
              .val(value)
              .attr("title", "")
              .addClass("custom-combobox-input ui-widget ui-widget-content ui-state-default ui-corner-left")
              .autocomplete({
                  delay: 0,
                  minLength: 0,
                  source: $.proxy(this, "_source")
              })
              .tooltip({
                  tooltipClass: "ui-state-highlight"
              });

            this._on(this.input, {
                autocompleteselect: function (event, ui) {
                    ui.item.option.selected = true;
                    this._trigger("select", event, {
                        item: ui.item.option
                    });
                },

                autocompletechange: "_removeIfInvalid"
            });
        },

        _createShowAllButton: function () {
            var input = this.input,
              wasOpen = false;

            $("<a>")
              .attr("tabIndex", -1)
              .attr("title", "Show All Items")
              .tooltip()
              .appendTo(this.wrapper)
              .button({
                  icons: {
                      primary: "ui-icon-triangle-1-s"
                  },
                  text: false
              })
              .removeClass("ui-corner-all")
              .addClass("custom-combobox-toggle ui-corner-right")
              .mousedown(function () {
                  wasOpen = input.autocomplete("widget").is(":visible");
              })
              .click(function () {
                  input.focus();

                  // Close if already visible
                  if (wasOpen) {
                      return;
                  }

                  // Pass empty string as value to search for, displaying all results
                  input.autocomplete("search", "");
              });
        },

        _source: function (request, response) {
            var matcher = new RegExp($.ui.autocomplete.escapeRegex(request.term), "i");
            response(this.element.children("option").map(function () {
                var text = $(this).text();
                if (this.value && (!request.term || matcher.test(text)))
                    return {
                        label: text,
                        value: text,
                        option: this
                    };
            }));
        },

        _removeIfInvalid: function (event, ui) {

            // Selected an item, nothing to do
            if (ui.item) {
                return;
            }

            // Search for a match (case-insensitive)
            var value = this.input.val(),
              valueLowerCase = value.toLowerCase(),
              valid = false;
            this.element.children("option").each(function () {
                if ($(this).text().toLowerCase() === valueLowerCase) {
                    this.selected = valid = true;
                    return false;
                }
            });

            // Found a match, nothing to do
            if (valid) {
                return;
            }

            // Remove invalid value
            this.input
              .val("")
              .attr("title", value + " didn't match any item")
              .tooltip("open");
            this.element.val("");
            this._delay(function () {
                this.input.tooltip("close").attr("title", "");
            }, 2500);
            this.input.autocomplete("instance").term = "";
        },

        _destroy: function () {
            this.wrapper.remove();
            this.element.show();
        }
    });
})(jQuery);

$(function () {
    $("#combobox").combobox();
    $("#toggle").click(function () {
        $("#combobox").toggle();
    });
});
```

PLEASE HELP

Comment: Which widget are you wanting (you have shown both autocomplete and combobox). The control should be a textbox - `<input type="text" ..>`. Refer [this example](http://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#remote) for using jquery autocomplete with a remote data source

Comment: Yes i can get it to work for an input type text, but i want it for my @htmldropdown, is there something you could suggest??????

Comment: What do you mean you want if for a drop down. They are 2 completely different things.

Comment: The first line of code in the question, i want that dropdown to work like this http://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#combobox

Comment: If you remove all the code in the 2nd code block (`$(".dd1").combobox();` etc) and then change helper to `@Html.DropDownList("combobox", Model.Sizes, "--select--")` - so it generates `<select id="combobox" ..>` then it should be fine (the last section of code refers to an element with `id="combobox"`)

Comment: Thats great stephen! Thanks again for your help, you are a wizard

Comment: THIS HAS CAUSED ANOTHER PROBLEM, since ive now changed the id of my dropdown, ive updated my other functions to match this new id, one of the functions auto filled my user form based on the id of the dropdown value and matching that to a row in my database! but nows its broke

Comment: Not sure what you mean. Did you have a property in your model named `selectSize` (in which case you should have been using `@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.selectSize, ...)` anyway). If so change your scripts to reference its `id` attribute - `$("#selectSize").combobox();` etc. or (not as good) override the `id` attribute using `@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.selectSize, ...new { id="combobox")`

Comment: its hard to say in the comments but ill try, the dropdown  @Html.DropDownList("combobox", Model.Sizes, "--select--") ,

Is now linked to the script  <script type="text/javascript">
        $(function () {
            $("[name='combobox']").change(function () {

                $.getJSON('@Url.Action("GetSize")', { sizeID: $("[name='combobox']").val() }, function (Size) {
                    // Fill the fields according to the Jsondata we requested

                    $("#KID").val(Size["KammID"]);

after adding the combobox this no longer works

Comment: Ive explained fully  with all the code in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29663559/pass-dropdown-combobox-value-with-json-auto-filling-userform cheers